# route CNAME with nginx and docker

Tags: docker, nginx, amazon-ec2, devops

I'm trying to achieve `api.com => api.myapp.com` without success.

**main nginx** run on aws/ec2 on docker and listen to port 80

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myapp.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app:80/;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80 l;
    server_name api.myapp.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://api:80/;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

**myapp.com** domain configured

**A Record** => @(host) => 1.10.10.30(aws-ec2/ip)

**A Record** => api(host) => 1.10.10.30(aws-ec2/ip)

with this configuration it works fine. visiting `myapp.com` resolves `app`, and `api.myapp.com` resolves api service.

(I hope it's ok until now, so let me know if it wrong way to do it)

### the problem

Now, I want to configure `api.com` with `CNAME` `api.myapp.com`.
I went to my domain manager(godaddy) and set as:

`CNAME` => `www` => `api.myapp.com`

when i visit `api.com` it resolves `myapp.com` and not `api.myapp.com`

what should i do?

Comment: `api.com` is not listed in a `server_name` directive, so Nginx will use the default server block, which happens to be the first one.

Comment: Thanks for response. if I'll configure it in my nginx. what's the purpose of configure `api.com` with CNAME? why I couldn't configure it with A Record `api.com`  => `ec2/ip` ? what the difference?

Comment: CNAME or A record make no difference to Nginx. The CNAME requires two DNS lookups so is less efficient than an A record. If you have control over the IP address of your service, you may as well use an A record. If someone else has control of the IP address and defined an A record to point at it, it may be more efficient for you to use a CNAME so that you do not need to concern yourself if the IP address ever changes.

Comment: thanks, I'm asking it because i saw (https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/domains/add-a-domain/using-existing-domains/connecting-domains) that shopify ask you to configure either CNAME and A-Record... i wonder why do they ask for them both? what am i missing?... this what i'm trying to achieve at the end. `customer.com` ==> `customer.myapp.com` like shopify does

Comment: shopify said to configure it like `customer.com` => `CNAME` => `www` => `customer.shopify.com` and also to add `customer.com` => `A Record` => `@` => `23.227.38.65(shopifyip)`... what's the purpose of it?

Comment: thanks!. sorry, could you explain in more details what do you mean separate IP please? I mean why does the customer care about 23.227.38.64(A Record)? I guess the customer want to CNAME `customer.com` => `shops.myshopify.com`.
so why the extra `A Record`?

Comment: does it not sounds quite redundant? CNAME will resolve the `shops.myshopify.com `which resolve the front shop. and A Record for redirect? is it no the same? ... and if those are two separate IP address so what does it mean? so if i visit `customer.com` what will be resolved? `shops.myshopify.com` or  `23.227.38.6`?

Comment: Note, that CNAME is not supported on the 2nd level domain, so you can only have A Record for `customer.com` (can't point it to CNAME). Not sure if this explains your issue, but pls double check in case it does.

Comment: @taleodor, ok so why don't use only `A Record`, i.e `A Record` => `@` => `23.227.38.65(shopifyip)` and `A Record` => `www` => `23.227.38.65(shopifyip)` ?

Comment: Idk, don't have experience with Shopify. My wild guess would be - they may be using CNAME to double check that you indeed intended to point your domain to Shopify. Also I don't really see how Shopify wires into your question - maybe if you would include this information into the scope, it would be easier to propose some answer. At least, you should understand that doing `CNAME => www => api.myapp.com` has no effect on api.com binding (without www).

Comment: take a look here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61544603/why-does-connect-domain-to-shopify-ask-for-either-cname-and-a-record?noredirect=1#comment108866860_61544603
so you can understand why I'm asking about shopify! thanks a lot for your helping

Comment: That other question - like I mentioned, probably they use CNAME to double check your intentions. However, for this question, can you clarify what exactly doesn't work. I mean if you're pointing your A Record and your CNAME to Shopify, then how your nginx gets engaged at all in the first place?

Comment: In this question, I set cname ‘api.com’ => ‘www’ => ‘api.myapp.com’. And I Expect to visit api.com and see api.myapp.com but I got myapp.com instead

Comment: Setting dns record for `www` has no affect on `api.com`. Why don't you simply point your `api.com` A Record to ip as Shopify suggests? What's the issue with that?

Comment: that's ok   if I set `A record` and configure in my nginx it works.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76594077/aws-route53-nginx-django-host-2-applications-with-cname

Answer (score 0):

I think you have one more L ，delete it

```
server {
    listen 80 ;
    server_name api.myapp.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://api:80/;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```