# why does connect domain to "Shopify" ask for either CNAME and A Record?

Tags: nginx, shopify, devops

why does connect domain to "Shopify" ask for either `CNAME` and `ARecord`? [ref](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/domains/add-a-domain/using-existing-domains/connecting-domains)

> If you've purchased your domain through a third party, then you need
>   to edit the following DNS settings:
>
> Your A record should point to Shopify's IP address, which is
>   23.227.38.65 Copy
>
> Your www CNAME record should point to `shops.myshopify.com` Copy .

I mean if i configure my domain `customer.com`, `A Record` => `23.227.38.65`

Isn't that enough to them? why do they also ask for `CNAME` `www` `shops.myshopify.com`?

Comment: Some people (and maybe some browsers) assume `www.example.com` because of a long standing convention. And they want those customers to find the shop hosted at `example.com`. So they are not asking for either a CNAME or an A record. They are asking you to point `example.com` at one service (that happens to be an IP address) and `www.example.com` at another service (that happens to have a DNS name).

Comment: oh I think i get it! because if you configure CNAME => www => shops.myshopify.com it would work only for `www.domain.com`, but not for `domain.com` , right? @RichardSmith

Comment: and why don't use only `A Record`, i.e `A Record` => `@` => `23.227.38.65(shopifyip)` and `A Record` =>` www ` => `23.227.38.65(shopifyip)` ?

Comment: Good question @Liam would also love to know why that is.

Answer (score 0):

"The shop subdomain points to Shopify’s servers, so they can manage which A record (IP address) the online store is hosted on."
https://www.domainnamesanity.com/blog/cname-vs-a-record/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).